# pyenv appends .zshrc file with spam at every `source`

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, zshrc, pyenv

I am trying to setup python 3.7.3 to be my default python.
I am following this guide https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac undre the chapter `What we should do` at the bottom of the page.

It works fine besides it appends my `.zshrc` file with:

```
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Every time I open the terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` it will put another of the following at the bottom of my config:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

I get python v2 if I remove `if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi`, change the `>> ~/.zshrc` to `>> ~/.zshrc_temp` or remove it completely 
Any ideas?

I am using MacOS Mojave 10.14 and iTerm2 if that matters.

Comment: I must admit I had the same problem, so you're not alone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem related to `pyenv`, you just don't understand what `.zshrc` is.

`.zshrc` is the init/config file for ZSH. Whenever you open a new interactive ZSH shell, ZSH run the content within.

```sh
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The content above appends the pyenv init script into `.zshrc` over and over.

I don't know where you copied the `echo -e ...` command. It's supposed run in the shell, not put into the `.zshrc`.

Comment: Ahh ofc. It was a bit unclear in the instructions on the site I linked.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this post because of the same issue, then I found out why it happened:
I followed the [instruction to install pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) incorrectly, by pasting the following command to `.zshrc`, which was supposed to be running in the terminal directly.

```bash
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

In order words, to solve the issue, you can simple remove these lines from the `.zshrc` and it will never bother you again.

Comment: Exactly what I did :D Thanks! Saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this! I complete removed

```
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and every

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

except one.

Pyenv still seems to work as intended after this and no new lines are being appended to my .zshrc

Answer (score 0):

I removed the...

echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc

from my .zshrc folder and I save it, however, these lines still show up in my folder when I terminate my window and open a new one.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35759587)